# JavaFx with Maven - Error Module 'sample' reads package 'javafx.beans' from both 'javafx.base' and 'javafx.base'

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx-11

After adding maven in JavaFX project in Intellij I get this error In module-info.java `Module 'sample' reads package 'javafx.beans' from both 'javafx.base' and 'javafx.base'`. I have practice many answers on this thread in SO. But nothing worked.

My pom.xml is follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>main.java.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>ThreeColumnTable</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>testResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/generated-groovy-stubs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>sample.App</mainClass>
                            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>sample.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My module-info.java is as follows :

```
module sample {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.datatransfer;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires javafx.web;

    opens sample to javafx.fxml;
    exports sample;
    //opens  sample;
}
```

I have tried many ways, but nothing worked. I have created module-info.java manually. So what is the wrong with the above code ?

Answer (score 3):

After struggling 3 or 4 days I have got some idea from an SO answer. The problem is when you add the dependecy javaFx in pom.xml, then again in module-info.java you requires the javaFx then the problem arise `Module 'sample' reads package 'javafx.beans' from both 'javafx.base' and 'javafx.base`'. So, I deleted the two dependecy from pom.xml :

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the problem has gone. Alhamdulillah.